# 1D array game on HackerRank

Tags: java, arrays, backtracking

I am trying to solve this problem on HackerRank for hours. The basic problem statement is as follows:

You have a 1D array consisting only of 0s and 1s . You start at the 0th index. 
Lets assume the size of array to be n. You win if you can reach beyond the scope of array(i.e to an index > n-1). But you can only move in two ways:

- Walk one step forward or backward.
- Make a jump of exactly 'm' length  forward.

ALSO, YOU CAN ONLY STEP ON AN ELEMENT WITH VALUE 0.
The value at 0th index is known to be 0. (so you start at a valid position)

'm' is provided as an input and it can be any value between 0 and 100 inclusive.
The array size can be any value between 2 and 100 inclusive.

The program should print "YES" if a win is possible. else "NO".

I tried solving it using a backtracking algorithm in Java. But it gets rejected for most test cases.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

         int n=sc.nextInt();
         int m=sc.nextInt();
         int[] array = new int[n];

         for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
             array[i]=sc.nextInt();
         }

         if(m<2){
             for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                  if(array[i] == 1){
                        System.out.println("NO");
                        break;
                    } 
                }
                System.out.println("YES");
            }

            else{
        if(isSolvable(array,0,m,n))  
        {System.out.println("YES");}
        else 
        {System.out.println("NO");}

        }

    }

    static boolean isSolvable(int[] array,int x,int m,int n){
        if(x>n-1){ 
            //System.out.print(x + " "); 
            return true;
        }
        if(array[x] == 1) return false;
        if(isSolvable(array,x+m,m,n)){
            //System.out.print(x + " "); 
            return true;
        }
        if(isSolvable(array,x+1,m,n)){
            //System.out.print(x + " "); 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't do this with backtracking, but just recursion, and I was able to solve the problem and get all test cases correct. The code that you've posted also doesn't do any backtracking. I also see that in your conditions, you're missing the condition to move backward by 1, which would cause you to fail some cases.

Eg: `0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1` with m=5.

With the above example, first you jump to x+m, then try x+m again, then try x+1, otherwise you get out.

To break this test case down:

```
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1

          ^ x+m True
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1

                    ^ x+m False
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1

            ^ x+1 False
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1

  ^ x+1 False
```

With your code, you would return false where instead to solve this, you would need to do the following:

```
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1

          ^ x+m

0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1

        ^ x-1
0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1

                  ^ x+m
```

Then two more x+m's to complete it to return true.

To complete this using your code, you need to add the condition to move back one space, BUT when doing so, you could incorporate an endless recursive loop Eg: (-1+1-1+1-1+1) which will cause a stackoverflow. One of the things I would suggest including would be a `boolean` array to hold memory of which spots you've seen before.

Comment: That test case you explained totally helped. It had not crossed my mind at all. Thanks a lot.
I just added the condition to move back one space in my function and changed the value of the position from 0 to 1 to mark it as a visited spot.That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Coding this game is a bit hard for an amateur but can explain the algorytm that i think will solve the problem.

First of all, i think that the points that you can go both one and "m" steps further is the key points of this problem. I mean you can choose another way from them. If you reach them 3 times so they are useless, etc etc. It's important to hold them in an array i think.

- Define an array as `WellPoints`
- Check for first point of array where you can go one step and "m" steps further both. Save it as `firstWellPoint` or `WellPoints[0]`.
- Try to reach this point by one or "m" steps with a simple backtracking algorytm. If you can't, it's simply "NO".
- If you can reach to `firstWellPoint`, define a `counter` to count how many times you visited `WellPoints`.
- While you are checking next steps for each point, also check if point is suitable for one step and m steps both. If one and m step further is "0" for both, place it to `WellPoints` array.
- Now, if next check won't be true, get back to last element of `WellPoints` array and also raise your `counter` by 1.
- When you find a new `WellPoint`, reset your `counter` to 1.
- If `counter` = 3, then delete this `WellPoint` and restart checking from one before this by other way, that means new last element of `WellPoint` array. It can decide the way by checking `counter` like if `counter`=1 try one steps and when you come here again, it means if `counter`=2 try m steps.
- if `WellPoint` arrays first element, or `firstWellPoint` as i explained is reached again by backtracking on `WellPoint` array 3 times, you will delete this `WellPoint` too so your array won't be able to walk on it to the end.
- If you reach to end of array so you know that...